# How to get Cell's currently using frequency GSM/CDMA (Android)

Tags: android, frequency

Is there any **Android** class/ api by which i can get current radio frequency of my 
cell whether GSM orCDMA. 
Any guidelines. 
Thanks

Comment: which frequency you are talking about ?

Comment: Need an app to get the current frequency being used by the phone's cell radio and display it when the app starts.  Needs to work on GSM and CDMA

Comment: Then Specify properly it in your question so that everyone can understand it and give you proper answer

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about it, but check the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) you may find the solution to get frequecny.

Comment: Did you get the Solution..?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned I would get the carrier name and then write intents depending on carrier.

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```